# SQL merge filed with duplicates Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with some duplicates Data, I want to merge the job and unit field in one field.

My data currently looks like this:

```
name       job1        Unit1_Level1       Unit1__Level2
-------------------------------------------------------
A          Teacher     Infomation      Information_office
A          Staff       Secretary       Secretary_office
A          Staff       Engineer        Engineer_office
B          Teacher     Finacial        Finacial_office
C          Teacher     Engineer        Engineer_office
C          Staff       Library         Library_office
D          Staff       Library         Library_office
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
name       job
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A          Teacher-Infomation-Information_office:Staff-Secretary-Secretary_office:Staff-Engineer-Engineer_office
B          Teacher-Finacial-Finacial_office
C          Teacher-Engineer-Engineer_office:Staff-Library-Library_office
D          Staff-Library-Library_office
```

I try the FOR XML PATH , but still have the duplicate row.

Please help me about the question, thank you.

Comment: which version or sqlserver you are using???

Comment: The results you Want are a Very poor structure. In fact, the structure you already have is Significantly better. Why do you want to regress from normalised to a messed up string delimited structure???

Answer (score 2):

In TSQL you could use STRING_AGG()

```
    select  STRING_AGG(concat(job1,'-', Unit1_level1, '-', Unit1_level2, ':'))  
    from your_table
```

Comment: Why would you enable such a horrible mess? :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this combination STRING_AGG an CONCAT_WS

```
SELECT  name, STRING_AGG(a.ct, ':'  )
FROM (
    SELECT name, CONCAT_WS('-', job1, Unit1_level1, Unit1__Level2, ':')   ct 
    FROM MyTable
) a
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as the following:

```
SELECT Name,
       STRING_AGG(CONCAT_WS('-', job1, Unit1_Level1, Unit1__Level2), ':')
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

String_Agg requires an separator value

```
 select  STRING_AGG(concat(job1,'-', Unit1_Level1, '-', Unit1_Level2, ':'),' ') a from @tmp
```